# multiple regexp in one input

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

hi i have one input type tel for mobile number and like use pattern for number format like this
 `938 119 1229` 
but when i use type tel i can use word in input 
i try use the two regex in one input but i don't know how :

```
function mobileNumInput(input){
    var regex = /[^0-9]/g;  //for digit only
    input.value=input.value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)/, '$1 $2 $3');   //for space between numbers
    input.value=input.value.replace(regex)      

}
```

and html :

```
<input type="tel" name="phone"  placeholder="912 000 0000" maxlength="12"  min="0" max="9" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"  onkeyup="mobileNumInput(this)"  autofocus>
```

this is my placeholder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSYr7.png)

i want this format :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t0f5.png)

But I don't want to use word like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMPmi.png)
sorry my english is bad

Comment: Can you please illustrate on an example what you are trying to achieve by each line of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to do the following:

1. Remove all non-numeric characters from the phone number.

   - Example: convert `'(111)-174-1234'` to `'1111741234'`
2. Add spaces in the correct location to the resultant number.

   - Example: convert `'1111741234'` to `'111 174 1234'`

If my assumptions about the purpose of this code are true, your code had two mistakes:

1. You put step #1 after step #2.

   - This led to an input `'(111)-174-1234'` having the regex (#2) running the following replacement: `.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)/, '$1 $2 $3')`
   - The above snippet of code only works on pure numbers. It does *not* recognize `'(111)-174-1234'` as containing any matches to `/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)/`, so no replacements are made. In other words, after line 3 of your code runs, `input.value` has likely not changed.
   - The solution to this is simply to switch line 3 and 4 in your program.
2. In step #1, you used `.replace(regex)` instead of `.replace(regex,'')`.

   - This is just a `String` method technicality: `String.prototype.replace` accepts a regex and a string to replace it. Leaving the second parameter empty is the same as setting the second parameter as `undefined`.
   - An example is that `"Hello world".replace(/l/g)` is the same as `"Hello world".replace(/l/g,undefined)`. The result of both of these snippets is `"Heundefinedundefinedo world"`. You can gain the desired behavior by using `"Hello world".replace(/l/g,'')` instead. This will return `"Heo world"`.

I put my fixes into a revised version of your code:

```
function mobileNumInput(input){
    var regex = /[^0-9]/g;  //for digit only
    input.value=input.value.replace(regex, ''); // Step #1 (remove non-digits)
    input.value=input.value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)/, '$1 $2 $3');   //Step #2 (add spaces to valid phone number)
}
```

Here is a slightly further modified version of your code with one test:

```
function mobileNumInput(input){
    input.value=input.value
      .replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')//Remove all non-digits
      .replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)/, '$1 $2 $3'); //Add spaces to the only-digit number 
}

function test(){
  var testInputElement=document.createElement("input");
  testInputElement.value='(123)-[456}  -  7890';//Horribly formatted phone number
  mobileNumInput(testInputElement);
  console.log(testInputElement.value);
}

test();
//123 456 7890
```